# Encrypt passwords in human-readable format

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I'm looking for one or more encryption algorithms that can encrypt passwords in a way that the encrypted text must be readable by humans.

For example if I give as *password*:

```
StackOverflow
```

The algorithm should gives me:

```
G0aThiR4i s0ieFer
```

So I want to get an encrypted password easily readable by humans (not strange strings with special chars or thousand of characters).

There are algorithms that fit this need?

Comment: How's yours "G0aThiR4i" is more readable than, for example, "84d7dc19766c446f5e4084e8fce87f82" ?

Comment: I't slightly shorter and with not a lot of numbers, and is readable (read 0 as O and 4 as A for example)

Comment: Your encrypted password is shorter than the original password.  How could that be?  Are you searching for hash-function or reversible encryption?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is security a major factor? Stream ciphers tend to be less secure than block ciphers, but will produce shorter encrypted strings. What are your plans for key distribution?

Comment: was just an example... I'm looking for human readable and not very long passwords.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I don't need the encrypted keys to be reversable, security is important in the direction of encrypted->decrypted, I mean, the original password must be keept safe.

Comment: Then why not just associate each password with a random key stored in a database?

Comment: Sorry I can't see how a random key stored in db can help.

Comment: I downvoted. You aren't encrypting anything; you're hashing passwords. Also, your guidelines (short, "human-readable") make your password storage system easy to crack (read, terrible). The fewer the bits that you store from the hash output, the easier it is to find collisions, as Timothy Shields pointed out.

Comment: I'm not going to store anything in database, I will just generate these easy and human readable passwords given a user defined one. I'm not going to explain the purpose of it because it's a lucrative project that is not ready to be shared. So live with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question puzzled me in many ways, leading to the hare-brained idea of creating a **completely human-readable paragraph** from a base 16 hash result. What's more readable than English sentences?

To maintain the security of a hashed password, the algorithm is as follows:

1. Hash a user's password using any of the basic techniques.
2. Run the hash through my special [HashViewer](http://jsfiddle.net/dgtWz/1/)
3. Enjoy the Anglicized goodness.

For example, if this Base16 hash is the input:

```
c0143d440bd61b33a65bfa31ac35fe525f7b625f10cd53b7cac8824d02b61dfc
```

the output from HashViewer would be this:

> Smogs enjoy dogs. Logs unearth backlogs. Logs devour frogs. Grogs decapitate clogs and dogs conceptualize fogs. Fogs greet clogs. Cogs conceptualize warthogs. Bogs unearth dogs despite bogs squeeze fogs. Cogs patronize catalogs. Cogs juggle cogs. Warthogs debilitate grogs; unfortunately, clogs juggle cogs. Warthogs detest frogs; conversely, smogs decapitate cogs. Fogs conceptualize balrogs. Smogs greet smogs whenever polywogs accost eggnogs. Logs decapitate frogs. Eggnogs conceptualize clogs. Dogs decapitate warthogs. (smogs )

(The last words in parenthesis were words that were left over)

In this glorious paragraph form, we can look at two separate hashes and easily compare them to see if they are different.

As an extra feature, there is a function to convert the English text back in to the hash string.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you this looks awesome, the problem is that the generated encrypted password is way too long for my purpose. I have a similar idea but with an algorithm not-reversable (I don't care to convert the encrypted string back to the original), using an user inserted password and an user inserted encryption key. I use the two inputs to generate a short number (3 or 4 digits) and I use each number to grab a noun, a verb and a conjunction. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Just truncate the input (like Timothy Shields suggested).

Answer (score 11):

RFC 1751, which defines a "Convention for Human-Readable 128-bit Keys" – basically just a mapping of blocks of bits to strings of English words.

For example, the 128-bit key of:

```
CCAC 2AED 5910 56BE 4F90 FD44 1C53 4766
```

would become

```
RASH BUSH MILK LOOK BAD BRIM AVID GAFF BAIT ROT POD LOVE
```

Algorithm is used for fixed-length 128-bit keys, that's a base for data size. Source data can be truncated or expanded to match the base.

Spec & implementation in C @ https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1751

It ain't well known. I couldn't find implementation mention apart from one in spec & references to lost python library.

Comment: Thiis looks very interesting. Is the entire code published in the link you've provided? I need to convert it to Javascript, I guess shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: I've just found this: `key2eng() assumes string referenced by
   engout has at least 60 characters
   (4*12 + 11 spaces + '\0') of space.` Does it mean that the entered password must be at least 60 characters??

Comment: 128 bit is a limit so you can truncate original passwords if they are longer and enrich them to needed length if shorter (pad with spaces?).

Comment: There are some other implementations:
[Haskell](https://github.com/xenog/rfc-1751),
[Ruby](https://github.com/ab/sixword),
[Rust](https://github.com/icasdri/rfc1751-rs),
[JavaScript](https://github.com/ms-brainwallet/ms-brainwallet.github.io)

Answer (score 2):

```
Step 1) Apply regular encryption algorithm.
Step 2) Base 26-encode it using letters a thru z
Step 3) ???
Step 4) Profit!
```

---

Even cooler would be to get a letter-bigraph distribution for the english language. Pick a simple pseudo-random-number algorithm and seed it with the non-human-readable password hash. Then use the algorithm to make up a word according to how likely a letter is to follow the letter before it in the english language. You'll get really english-sounding words, and consistently from the same seed. The chance for collisions might be unseasonably high, though.

Comment: For my purpose I don't care if two passwords are encrypted with the same result. I don't understand your edit, may you explain it a bit clearer? thanks

Comment: Yeah, what you do is, you get an english language [letter bigram frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram#Bigram_Frequency_in_the_English_language). You can use it to implement an algorithm that generates random english-looking words. Then you seed the randomizer with the original password so you get consistent results. They'll end up looking [something like this](http://johno.jsmf.net/knowhow/ngrams/index.php?table=en-bible-char-3gram&paragraphs=5&length=100), although those are trigrams

Comment: There aren't already prepared codes that use this method? (PHP, C, JS, everything is ok, I'll convert it to JS)

Comment: @FezVrasta: there should be, unfortunately I don't have the spare time to look right now.. try googling around for "letter bigram word generator" or something along those lines. it's not very difficult to implement though. just map each letter to a dict of `(next_letter, probability)` pairs, then for each current letter, pick a random next_letter weighted by the probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

EncryptedPassword = Base64(SHA1(UTF8(Password) + Salt))

Password is string
Salt is cryptographically strong random byte[]

UTF8: string -> byte[]
SHA1: byte[] -> byte[]
Base64: byte[] -> string

EncryptedPassword is string

Store (EncryptedPassword, Salt).

Throw in whatever encryption algorithm you want instead of SHA1.

For example, if password is `StackOverflow` you get the encrypted password `LlijGz/xNSRXQXtbgNs+UIdOCwU`.

Comment: @FezVrasta You can truncate the byte[] you get out of SHA1 before converting to Base64 to get a shorter EncryptedPassword. For example, if I truncate to 4 bytes, I get the EncryptedPassword `LlijGw`. If you make it too short, you're going to run the risk of many incorrect passwords being incorrectly accepted.

Comment: I will never try to get the original password from the encrypted one, so I guess it's not a problem.